# How can I align these two figures vertically in one column?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, minipage

How can I align these two figures vertically in one column? I want to combine them into one float with two figures and two captions instead.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!t]
\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{caption 1}
\label{fig:label 1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{caption 2}
\label{fig:label 2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}    
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## New answer

### Separated float

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{caption 1}
\label{fig:label 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{caption 2}
\label{fig:label 2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### two float in one page

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{caption 1}
\label{fig:label 1}
\vspace*{\floatsep}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{caption 2}
\label{fig:label 2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

### [image]

## Old answer

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{caption 1}
\label{fig:label 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{caption 2}
\label{fig:label 2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Add

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Case I]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig_first_case}}\\
\subfloat[Case II]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig_second_case}}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want to combine them into one float.

Comment: @hana I added the answer.

Comment: How can I use two figures and two captions as in the original?

Comment: @hana Maybe you mean subfigure. You should clearly describe the effect you want at one time.

Comment: Nope, I don't want to use (a), (b). They're two separate figures but I just want to make them go together.

Comment: @hana Your needs are very confusing. Generally, each floating body has only one caption. I don't understand why you don't accept two float. What's the problem with this?

Comment: I want them to stay together. If I just use two floats then there are some cases that they're splited by text.

Comment: @hana If you use default postion, i.e., `tbp`, it will not splited by text.

Comment: The figures are supposed to placed on top only.

Comment: @hana Please check the update at the top. I think this should be the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [@Clara's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656809/31283) answer, add `float` package and use the optional argument `[H]`. Since you want your figures in the exact place on a page, you don't really need the float mechanism

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{caption 1}\label{fig:label 12}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{caption 2}\label{fig:label 22}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably it's not clear but I want them to be float. I want them to stay together like subfigure but not label them as (a), (b) instead of labeling them as seperate caption and figures.